# Looking for font based on E shape used on French ID Card

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation

I'm looking for a font where the 'E' is similar to this (note the middle stick)

[image]

Any suggestion ?

### Edit:

It's not OCR_B, as OCR_B is only used in MRZ section.

Source of the font: French ID Card

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Retro Bold Plain](https://www.wfonts.com/font/retro-bold-let) via wfonts.com

[image]

[Santiago BTN](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/btn/santiago-btn/) via Myfonts.com

[image]

[Ansley Display](https://dribbble.com/shots/2281308-Ansley-Display-Free-Font) via dribble.com

[image: Ansley]

[War Club](https://creativemarket.com/scottsmoker/114016-War-Club-Font?u=designshack) via creativemarket.com

[image]